# AttributeError: __enter__ в with

Tags: python, aiogram

Первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь, даже не знаю что написать

```
@dp.message_handler(state=command.userOff)
async def userOff(message:types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as users:
        users = users.read().split()
        for i in range(len(users)):
            if int(message.text) % 4 == 0 or int(message.text) == 0:
                with(f'{users[int(message.text)]}/closed.txt', 'w') as closed:
                    await closed.write('true')
                    await state.finish()
            else:
                await message.reply('Выбран не тот пользователь, введите цифру заново')
                break
```

Ошибка:

```
File "path", line 78, in userOff
    with(f'{userss[int(message.text)]}/closed.txt', 'w') as closed:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пропустили `open`:

```
    with open(f'{users[int(message.text)]}/closed.txt', 'w') as closed:
        await closed.write('true')
        await state.finish()
```